# insert html tags into replace function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to wrap `Aufpreis` in bold html tags to highlight this but if I insert html it treats them as part of the string, how can I insert html tags?

**data**

```
[item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4]
```

**app.js**

```
const Items = getItems(state).map((item) => {
            return {
            label: `${item.alias.replace('item', '')}(<b>Aufpreis</b>: ${item.value}euro)`,
            value: item.alias
            };
          });


const App = ({Items}) => (
{Items}
)
```

Comment: What are you doing with these Items?

Comment: I am returning this in jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign JSX to the object property instead of assigning a string.

There needs to be a grouping tag, surrounding your elements. If you don't want to use a `div` you can use a `Fragment` tag ([React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)) and wrap any code evaluation you need to do between `{}`.

```
label: <React.Fragment>{item.alias.replace('item', '')}<b>Aufpreis</b>:({item.value}euro)</React.Fragment>
```

or

```
label: <div>{item.alias.replace('item', '')}<b>Aufpreis</b>:({item.value}euro)</div>
```

Comment: If I add `<div`> tags I then get the following warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.1:$[object Object]`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used., I've tried adding keys but it still errors?

Comment: @tomharrison Add a `key` to your `div` with some unique value. eg. `<div key={item.alias}>`